# How to set environment variables in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, environment-variables

How do I set environment variables in Visual Studio 2012?

For example, I need to set this:

```
$(MyDir) = "c:\my_dir"
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? is this required for building the solution? You can otherwise use a pre- or post build event to set this value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the project in a text editor, and into the top existing  tag add

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyDir>c:\my_dir</MyDir>
  ...(leave existing ones here)...
</PropertyGroup>
```

There's probably some way to do this in the UI, but I only ever edit the files by hand nowadays. And its a different UI for every language(!)

Comment: There is an existing property group for globals (Label="Globals").