# how should i change the value of QTDIR in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, macros, qt5

the include path for qt project in VS2012 is ($(QTDIR)\include\QtWidgets) and clearly this QTDIR is not defined correctly on my computer...

is there any way of fixing this?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the Qt Visual Studio Add-in:
1) You should open "Qt options" window and use "Add" button on the "Qt versions" tab.
2) Right click on your project in the "Solution Explorer", choose "Change project's Qt version" and select the correct Qt version. $(QTDIR) should be used automatically.

If you are not using Qt Visual Studio Add-in (It's unavailable for the express versions of VS), try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718193/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-vs2012) solution.

Comment: well, i am pretty sure i was using the right Qt version settings for VS. just that i found the definition of QTDIR is in fact in  the user file(vcproj.user). without that file, vs cannot tell where QTDIR is...

Comment: Just right now I've tried to open a Qt project via the Qt VS add-in (Qt5->Open Qt project file) and it works very well. The generated user file (*.vcxproj.user) contains the QTDIR variable (that was set in the Qt VS add-in) for each <PropertyGroup>. If you have it, try to check are the all PropertyGroups contain the QTDIR variable. Then check is the QTDIR correct.

Comment: the thing is--the supposedly auto-generated user file is not there so that causes the definition of QTDIR missing

Answer (score 0):

It Seems Qt Visual Studio Add-in is not generating the .user file. We use this addin to genration solution files and project files. So, replacing {QTDIR} with the exact location will solve the issue temporarily because we generally generate the .vcproj files one time.