# Visual Studio environmant variable not recognized by C++ stdlib getenv

Tags: c++, visual-studio, environment-variables, getenv

I have a C++ project on windows, on which I use the `getenv` method from `stdlib` to get the value of an environment variable `$MyVar`
When I set the variable `MyVar` in a cmd and then call my program in the command line, everything works.
But when I call it from Visual Studio (2012), the program see `$MyVar` as unset.

To try and set it in Visual Studio I have tried to use a Property Sheet to define a macro `MyVar` as an environment variable ([cf. image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxG5V.jpg)) but the `getenv` method from `stdlib` doesn't see it.

[Screenshot of the window where I tried to define the env variable in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxG5V.jpg)

Is there a way to define my environment variable in Visual Studio in a way that the `getenv` method from `stdlib` would recognize it ?

Thank you all in advance for your help

**EDIT :**
I know that the `getenv` method would recognize `MyVar` if I defined it as a global env variable, but that is not a solution for me because I want to be able to launch several instances of my program at the same time with different values for `MyVar`.
I need a way to define a local env variable in Visual Studio that would be recognized by my program when I launch it from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is: there are different environments, so once you create a var in one env it doesn't appear at others.

1) Once you create cmd session, OS creates a dedicated environment for it. So, once you create a var in the prompt any app launched in this cmd would be able to see that var. Once you kill that cmd all the vars are gone too.

2) If you need global change of environment vars, you have to visit "Advanced System Settings" dialog (Control Panel\System and Security\System) then click "Environment variables" button and do your edits. Note: you may need to restart child sessions to let them see a change in global env vars.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I actually already know about this, but what I would like to do is to create a local env variable, in the environment in which Visual Studio starts the program.
I would like to be able to launch several instances of my program at the same time with different values for my environment variable so I don't want to define a global env variable for `MyVar`.
Therefore : is there a way to define a local env variable in Visual Studio in the place where VS would launch my program ?

Comment: It seems to be worth upgrading your VS. At 2015 and 2017 versions I can see the env setup for debug. And this can be found for 2012: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529919/setting-c-debug-environment-in-visual-studio-2012-express

Answer (score 0):

After latest updates described by you, I would advise to use command-line arguments instead of (or accompanied with) environment level vars. They're instance-specific, easy-to-implement etc.

And, more important, they're stateless.

Comment: I think you are right, but the problem is that I am not working alone on this project and unfortunately I don't have a choice, I am obligated to use an env variable instead of an argument